# Get current path to -what- triggered the pipeline (Yaml)

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've tried to echo / debug most of the variables here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml but none of them shows -what- triggered the pipeline.

If `MyDir` is a directory tree with `n` subdirectories containing files, I want to know what file actually triggered my pipeline (path to file)

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - MyDir/*
```

I use Git, and I have experimented with `Git log` but
`git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only` seems to produce somewhat ok results.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I ended up doing a Bash script that iterates over the files in the current commit. I needed them in a later step

Comment: Hmm.  You could use the API to find the last build of the pipeline for the current branch (or failing that the last build of your main branch).  From there, you can get the commit that the previous build ran on.  At this point you can calculate the changes between the commits (rather than just using `HEAD~1`) and work out which files are the relevant changes.  There may be better ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure DevOps specifically, but a lot of these systems can have multiple triggers, and if they won't tell you which trigger(s) *caused* them to run, the only way you could possibly find out is "magic": you'd need to know what the "before" state was, what happened, and what triggers they could have had and to repeat all the logic in them. So it's usually unwise to set up any system that cares *why* it was run, unless the system itself will tell you right out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if two commits happens at the same time I still don't know what actually triggered my pipeline.

It's not clear how you implemented two commits at the same time.

You could using following task with Git command to list the changes files:

```
- powershell: |
      ## get the changed files
      $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
      $temp=$files -split ' '
      $count=$temp.Length
      echo "Total changed $count files"
     
      $files | ForEach-Object {
        echo $_
          }
```

If you enable CI, each commit will start a separate build, then we will get the modified file name and path in each build.

[image]

If you submit a commit locally, and each commit contains multiple files that are modified, we can use the ForEach loop to output the list and path of the modified file names：

[image]

Comment: Leo, do exacly this but in a Bash task. I guess it's not an issue if two team members commit/merge at the same time